# Does Revivifying Mutagen and Perpetual Infusions break the HP economy?

Tags: feats, healing, pathfinder-2e

Revivifying Mutagen is a level 2 alchemist feat that allows you to metabolize the power of a mutagen you're under and regain HP based on the level of the mutagen in question.  It takes an action.  Perpetual infusions (if you are either a lvl 7+ mutagenicist or a lvl 8+ alchemist who has taken Perpetual Breadth for a mutagen) allows you to create (relatively low-level, quickly-expiring) mutagens for free, all day long, at a cost of an action per.  Drinking the thing also isn't high-cost.  It seems, then, that with that combination, you could rapidly heal yourself back to full from whatever level of damage at no resource cost.  What I've seen elsewhere in the game suggests that healing is generally a daily or at best hourly resource.  Is there something I'm missing here that makes this combination less cheesy than it appears?

Of particular interest because Revivifying Mutagen is only a level 2 feat, and is thus available to basically anyone via the Alchemist archetype for 2 feats (Alchemist Dedication and Basic Concoction).  Two feats isn't nothing, certainly, but if the result is that the party alchemist can rapidly heal everyone up to max after every fight for effectively no cost....

Comment: Any good champion can do Lay on Hands every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Not only is this within balance, it might be a weak use of the feats

*Early on* it may take a significant amount of time to heal up, but by level 7-8 (when this is truly functional) using the Medicine skill to heal up between encounters is a simple affair. The Treat Wounds activity takes 10 minutes, so if you're *really* down to the wire, that my cause a problem.

However, anyone who invests in [Ward Medic](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=864) (level 2) can heal entire small parties for significant amounts, and anyone who invested in [Continual Recovery](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=771) (also level 2) can heal even the most wounded allies to full in short order... and they're not mutually exclusive. A single Cleric with those two feats and the Class feat [Magic Hands](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1700) can maintain an entire party.

[Revivifying Mutagen](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=97) is an action you gain, not an action applied to Mutagens you make, so it only allows *you* to heal for 1d6 (not counting spending resources) until level 17, when it becomes 5d6. You do this using essentially your entire turn (Make/Consume Mutagen and activate Revivifying), or 10x per minute. You won't tax your party healer anymore, and you may be the first one ready to fight again, but you're definitely not breaking anything.